# SQL Question: Getting Datediff in days elapsed for each record in a group

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, datediff

Given this table:

[image]

How can I get the datediff in days between each status_date for each group of ID_Number?  In other words I need to find the number of elapsed days for each status that the ID_Number has been given.

Some things to know:

- All ID_Number will have a received_date which should be the earliest date for each ID_Number (but app doesn't enforce)
- For each ID_Number there will be a status with a corresponding status_date which is the date that the ID_Number was given that particular status.
- The status column doesn't always necessarily go in the same order every time (app doesn't enforce)
- All ID_Number will have a closed_date which should be the latest date (but app doesn't enforce)

Sample output:
So for ID_Number 2001, the first date (received_date) is 2009-05-02 and the next date you encounter has a status of 'open' and is 2009-05-02 so elapsed days is 0.  Moving on to the next date encountered is 2009-05-10 with a status of 'invest' and the elapsed days is 8 counting from the prior date.  The next date encountered is 2009-07-11 and the elapsed days is 62 counting from the previous date.

**Edited to add:**

Is it possible to have the elapsed days end up as a column on this table/view?
I also forgot to add that this is SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I added all the columns to my answer to replicate the original table with a new column of days. It is null when there is no closed_date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that you need the difference between the first status_date and the next status_date for the same id and so on up to the closed_date.

This will only work in SQL 2005 and up.

```
;with test as (
    select 
        key,
        id_number,
        status,
        received_date,
        status_date,
        closed_date,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by status_date, key ) as rownum
    from @test
    )
select 
    t1.key,
    t1.id_number,
    t1.status,
    t1.status_date,
    t1.received_date,
    t1.closed_date,
    datediff(d, case when t1.rownum = 1 
                then t1.received_date
                else    
                    case when t2.status_date is null 
                        then t1.closed_date 
                        else t2.status_date 
                    end
            end,
            t1.status_date
         ) as days
from test t1
left outer join test t2
on t1.id = t2.id
    and t2.rownum = t1.rownum - 1
```

This solution will work with SQL 2000 but I am not sure how good will perform:

```
select *,
    datediff(d,
        case when prev_date is null
            then closed_date
            else prev_date
        end,
        status_date )
from ( 
    select *,
        isnull( ( select top 1 t2.status_date 
          from @test t2
          where t1.id_number = t2.id_number
            and t2.status_date < t1.status_date
          order by t2.status_date desc
          ),received_date) as prev_date 
    from @test t1
) a
order by id_number, status_date
```

***Note***: Replace the @Test table with the name of your table.

Comment: I have modified the results based on the sample output you added to your question.

Comment: Ugh.  It looks like this will be pretty ugly to implement in sql2000 which is information I forgot to add to my original post.

Comment: @GregD: Is the KEY column always going to be continuous for each ID_Number?

Comment: The KEY column is an identity column and is auto incrementing.  Having said that, there is no guarantee that the identity column will always be in order with anything else.  These are really funky dates added in as an afterthought in this app and there are no business rules on them.

Comment: @GregD: I added a SQL 2000 compatible query, but I am not sure how good it will perform against big tables.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample output would really help, but this is a guess at what you mean, assuming you want that information for each ID_Number/Status combination:

```
select ID_Number, Status, EndDate - StartDate as DaysElapsed
from (
    select ID_Number, Status, min(coalesce(received_date, status_date)) as StartDate, max(coalesce(closed_date, status_date)) as EndDate
    from Table1
    group by ID_Number, Status
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky bit is determining the previous status and putting it on the same row as the current status. It would be simplified a little if there were a correlation between `Key` and `StatusDate` (i.e. that `Key(x) > Key(y)` always implies `StatusDate(x) >= StatusDate(y)`). Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case.

PS: I am assuming `Key` is a unique identifier on your table; you haven't said anything to indicate otherwise.

```
SELECT  Key,
        ID_Number, 
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 Key
        FROM    StatusUpdates prev
        WHERE   (prev.ID_Number = cur.ID_Number)
            AND (   (prev.StatusDate < cur.StatusDate)
                OR  (   prev.StatusDate = cur.StatusDate
                    AND prev.Key < cur.Key
                    )
                )
        ORDER BY StatusDate, Key /*Consider index on (ID_Number, StatusDate, Key)*/
        ) PrevKey
FROM    StatusUpdates cur
```

Once you have this as a basis, it's easy to extrapolate to any other info you need from the current or previous StatusUpdate. E.g.

```
SELECT  c.*,
        p.Status AS PrevStatus,
        p.StatusDate AS PrevStatusDate,
        DATEDIFF(d, c.StatusDate, p.StatusDate) AS DaysElapsed
FROM    (
        SELECT  Key,
                ID_Number, 
                Status,
                SattusDate,
                (
                SELECT  TOP 1 Key
                FROM    StatusUpdates prev
                WHERE   (prev.ID_Number = cur.ID_Number)
                    AND (   (prev.StatusDate < cur.StatusDate)
                        OR  (   prev.StatusDate = cur.StatusDate
                            AND prev.Key < cur.Key
                            )
                        )
                ORDER BY StatusDate, Key
                ) PrevKey
        FROM    StatusUpdates cur
        ) c
        JOIN StatusUpdates p ON
            p.Key = c.PrevKey
```